# Removing a generic type node with the smallest value in a doubly linked list Java

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

This is the code I have for my getSmallest() method:

```
public T getSmallest() throws EmptyListException
{
    if(isEmpty())
        throw new EmptyListException("List is empty");


    DLNode<T> current = front;
    DLNode<T> minNode = current;
    int minimum = current.getValue();

    while(current.getNext() != null)
    {
        if(minimum > current.getValue())
        {
            minNode = current;
            minimum = current.getValue();
        }

        current = current.getNext();    
    }

    return current.getData();
}
```

Each node has a String called dataItem and an integer called value associated with it. I want to see which node has the smallest value and then return the dataItem. The problem is that I'm stuck in the while loop and don't know why.
How would I properly traverse the list so that I don't get stuck in the while loop and can compare the minimum values?

Comment: Did you debug your loop to see why it never exits?

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, you can't overload operators in Java, and `>` will only apply to numeric datatypes.

The generic solution for this is to have `T extends Comparable<T>` and use its `compareTo` method:

```
DLNode<T> current = front;
DLNode<T> minNode = current;
T minimum = current.getValue();

while (current.getNext() != null) {
    if (minimum.compareTo(current.getValue()) > 0) {
        minNode = current;
        minimum = current.getValue();
    }

    current = current.getNext();    
}

return current.getData();
```

(alternatively, if `T` isn't a `Comparable`, you could supply a custom `Comparator` and use it in a similar fashion).

Answer (score 0):

The question is: why is the loop termination condition never reached?

As a doubly-linked list, does your list connect the last element to the first element?  Will `getNext()` ever answer null?

Also, there are problems in the loop as written. See the corrected code, below. The problem of loop termination is probably not fixed by this update.

```
public T getSmallest() throws EmptyListException {
    if ( isEmpty() ) {
        throw new EmptyListException("List is empty");
    }

    DLNode<T> currentNode = front;

    int minValue = currentNode.getValue();
    DLNode<T> minNode = currentNode;

    while ( (currentNode = currentNode.getNext()) != null ) {
        int nextValue = currentNode.getValue();
        if ( nextValue < minValue ) {
            minNode = currentNode;
            minValue = nextValue;
        }
    }

    return minNode.getData();
}
```

Comment: Please combine your two answers. Or delete the one no longer needed.